# detect scroll to bottom with 2 scroll in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a `div` with 2 scroll. I like when scroll to ended a message is displayed to the user.

this is my div:

```
<div id="scrollbox">
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
    <div>this is a test.this is a test.this is a test.this is a test</div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#scrollbox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and this my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrollbox").scroll("scroll",function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).outerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert(1);
        }
    });
});
```

When the div have one scroll Everything works well.
I've made that you can see. http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/

But when the div has two scroll is problematic.
The problem is that when scrolling to the ends back together several messages is displayed to the user.
I've made that you can see. http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/1/

**NOTE: This problem only in the Firefox browser.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
$(this).outerHeight()
```

with

```
$(this)[0].clientHeight
```

I forked it with the change and it solved the problem in my FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/7c1runn4/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks its worked. [http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/2/)

Comment: The correct address is: [http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/L5f7qtux/3/)